# openconnect is connected but does not use the right dns

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

```sh
sudo openconnect --protocol=nc [corporate vpn url]
GET [corporate vpn url]
Connected to [corporate vpn ip]:443
SSL negotiation with [corporate vpn url]
Connected to HTTPS on [corporate vpn url]
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
GET [corporate vpn url]/auth/url_13/welcome.cgi
SSL negotiation with [corporate vpn url]
Connected to HTTPS on [corporate vpn url]
frmLogin
username: [a username]
password: [a password]
POST [corporate vpn url]/auth/url_13/login.cgi
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved
GET [corporate vpn url]/home/starter0.cgi?check=yes
Connected as [new ip address], using SSL, with ESP in progress
ESP session established with server
```

It seems to be fine in the sense that [torguard](https://torguard.net/whats-my-ip.php) shows a different IP address and country before and after the openconnect is connected.

However it seems I cannot access to the corporate websites, when I try with say Chrome, I end up with:

```
Server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Like if the dns wasn't fetched or something like.

It's weird though cause when I am doing this from a live cd, that is without any prior connection to any network, it works just fine...

I am wondering how the DNS is fetched.

---

[EDIT]

I am right now using Linux Mint live to see what is the DNS in use or is there anything special setup:

For the Wireless connection:

```
mint@mint:~$ nmcli device show wlp1s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:94:67:32:46:AF
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     [our wireless hotspot at home]
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.104/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = [what an ip address?!], nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = [yet another one!], nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = [an address, geez], nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 0
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         [ipv 6 craziness]
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         [woooa]
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         [asdasdad]
IP6.GATEWAY:                            [&*^$]
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = [incredible]::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = [beyond understanding], mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             [fantastic!]
```

And the VPN created interface:

```
mint@mint:~$ nmcli device show tun0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         tun0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1400
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     tun0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         [magic ip]
IP4.GATEWAY:                            0.0.0.0 
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = [magic ip], nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         [magic ip again]
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

Interestingly enough, it seems that the `etc/resolv.conf` has been changed when I connected to the vpn:

```
#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

options edns0
nameserver [some address 1]
nameserver [some address 2]
search home [loads of corporate related names]
```

... and when I disconnect from the VPN:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search home
```

Comment: How is your OpenConnect configured?  Does your remote OpenConnect server at your company *set* DNS for OpenConnect connections?  If not, then this is a configuraiton issue at their end.

Comment: I don't know how it is configured, just like "out of Ubuntu install configured" (or lack of thereof).

Comment: @ThomasWard I think it has more to do with something on my side.
See right now I am using another laptop with a live usb of linux mint use openconnect and everything works like a charm... (with the same command as I used in my post)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found something that works from an answer on the Manjaro Forum: 
[Weird DNS issue over VPN](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/weird-dns-issue-over-vpn/78092/12)

So basically what did I do:

> - `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved`
> - `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`
> - Remove symlink between `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`
> - Comment out the line with `hosts: ...` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
> - Reboot

Tbh, it's still a bit voodoo to me about why it works.

The hypothetical underlying reason about why this works from the author is pasted below:

> My understanding is that commenting out the line with hosts in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` allows `sudo openconnect` to work without `systemd-resolved`. Indeed, openconnect relies on `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` to detect which type of DNS resolver is used and if it finds a row containing the word "resolve" in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, it thinks `systemd-resolved` is being used even if it is disabled.
>
> This is why I got an error when using `sudo openconnect` with `systemd-resolved` disabled. And this is also why I did enable this service afterwards. However it seems this caused some errors and even if the symlink technique did work, I was still having some issues with DNS leaks. Well, simply commenting this line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is what is recommended in the above link and it indeed works. Now, although systemd-resolved is being disabled (the default in Manjaro apparently), `sudo openconnect` does't complain anymore about it and works properly.
>
> I don't know whether `vpnc-script` is at fault here: it should not detect `systemd-resolved` as the DNS resolver being used based on that row in `nsswitch.conf`. It should check if `systemd-reolved` is enabled IMHO.

Comment: This kind of made it work, but it has made Firefox very slow.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. I was due to a [known bug. This workaround](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openconnect/-/issues/33#note_889793) worked for me:

add this to `/etc/network/if-up.d/globalprotect`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Hacky workaround bug in NM not setting the default routes.
if [ "$IFACE" = "vpn0" ]; then
  ip route replace default via 0.0.0.0 dev vpn0
fi
```

Comment: For others; don't forgot to use `chmod +x`

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since https://askubuntu.com/a/1169474/620001 made Firefox extremely slow to start and to open links, I have no idea why, I could, thank God, solve it differently.

I removed symlink between `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

I added my won DNS configuration to `/etc/resolv.conf`. In my case I choose:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
search .
```

I've added another one with the VPN configuration called: `/etc/resolv.conf.vpn`. Then, I implemented a script to copy this file to `/etc/resolv.conf` when network is up; the script also remove the lines when the network is down.

The `/etc/resolv.conf.vpn` file looks like this, the first lines are the lines I got from `/etc/resolv.conf` after connecting with Cisco AnyConnect since Cisco changes `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
domain x.com # My VPN domain
nameserver x.x.x.x # My VPN DNS
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
search .
```

My script `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90restart-resolved.sh` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
IF=$1
STATUS=$2
 
if [ "$IF" == "vpn0" ] && [ "$STATUS" == "up" ]
then
        echo "copying vpn dns file..."
        cp /etc/resolv.conf.vpn /etc/resolv.conf
        echo "restarting systemd resolved..."
        systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
fi

if [ "$IF" == "vpn0" ] && [ "$STATUS" == "down" ]
then
        echo "removing vpn dns lines..."
        sed -i '/domain x.com/d' /etc/resolv.conf
        sed -i '/nameserver x.x.x.x/d' /etc/resolv.conf
        echo "restarting systemd resolved..."
        systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
fi
```

PS. Removing the symlink also made my internet work after disconecting Cisco AnyConnect. Before that, my internet stopped working because DNS didn't get back to normal, it would only work after restarting `systemd-resolved`.

Answer (score -4):

Try to flush dns.

- Launch Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- Type the following command, then press Enter:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
  ```
- Now, type

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
  ```
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Note that these commands may not work properly on *newer* systems, where Netplan or `systemd-resolved` are powering the networking and resolvers.  Just a thought.